# Decoding Hex value in solidity

Tags: solidity, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am trying to view values stored on my ethereum contract using ethereum wallet. Currently the values are being placed onto the contract in hex format. Is there a way to decode them on the contract so that Ethereum wallet can read back words rather than hex values?

Comment: Could you show source code of your contract?  Usually, smart contracts store values in binary rather than hex format, so you are probably misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use **web3.utils.hexToAscii(hex)**

check documentation: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#hextoascii

Comment: Or `web3.toAscii` if web3 version is 0.x.